# Why is ssh-add adding duplicate identity keys?

Tags: 10.04, ssh, ssh-agent

I have created a private/public SSH key pair using `ssh-keygen`. I use this to authenticate to remote servers. However, I find that when I log in, `ssh-add -l` already lists my identity key even though I have not added it!

If I use the command `ssh-add` it prompts me for my passphrase and loads my identity key. If I then list my keys with `ssh-add -l`, it now shows two identity keys! These are obviously the same as both have the same fingerprint, but their descriptions are different (the automatically loaded one is "user@host (RSA)" and the one added using ssh-add is "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)").

So why does my identity key appear to be loaded without any action on my part, and why does ssh-add add the same key again? Obviously something must be doing this automatically, but what is it, and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ssh-keygen` creates a key `~.ssh/id_rsa` or `~.ssh/id_dsa`. These are the default file locations for ssh keys and are read in automatically. Use `ssh-add` when you need to add extra keys.

If you don't want a default key simply name your keys something other than `id_rsa`. This can be done when generating `ssh-keygen -f keyname` or simply by renaming the file.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu [keychain](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/keychain.1.html) could be doing the initial load of your identity.
More likely, your ssh-agent itself is grabbing the identities it needs to make password-free ssh (and scp, rsync, sftp, etc) possible for the logged-in user. Ubuntu uses your desktop login credentials to allow the ssh-agent to load identities from any of the several default locations in ~/.ssh.
Just like logging into a remote server, logging into your local desktop starts up the ssh-agent daemon.

Try `pgrep ssh-agent` and kill it if you like to enter your passwords a lot. But requiring passwords all the time is less secure than trusting the agent -- remembering them, keeping them secure, shoulder surfers, keyloggers, webcam peeping, history files, typing them at the wrong prompt and revealing them to the wrong server/daemon, ... the list goes on.